# SwiftUI - onDeleteCommand doesn't work with NavigationSplitView on macOs

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm working on a macOs 13 app and I'm using the new `NavigationSplitView`. The problem is that it doesn't let us use the `.onDeleteCommand(perform:)` (or maybe i'm using it wrong). Here is what I did :

In order to use the `.onDeleteCommand(perform:)`, the view needs to be focused. I did a simple app showing 3 rectangles that I can select with the **TAB** key, and when I hit **DELETE** key or in the menu bar **Edit > Delete** (both trigger the `.onDeleteCommand`), it switches to white or to its original colour.

```swift
VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.blue) ? Color.white : Color.blue))
        .padding()
        .focusable()
        .focused($focusedColor, equals: .blue)

    Rectangle()
        .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.red) ? Color.white : Color.red))
        .padding()
        .focusable()
        .focused($focusedColor, equals: .red)

    Rectangle()
        .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.yellow) ? Color.white : Color.yellow))
        .padding()
        .focusable()
        .focused($focusedColor, equals: .yellow)
}
.onDeleteCommand {
    if let focusedColor {
        if !isColorDeleted.contains(focusedColor) {
            isColorDeleted.append(focusedColor)
        } else {
            let idx = isColorDeleted.firstIndex(of: focusedColor)!
            isColorDeleted.remove(at: idx)
        }
    }
}
```

^^^ This works as it should ^^^

But if you put it in a `NavigationSplitView` like this :

```swift
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
    List {
        Text("Main page")
    }
} detail: {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.blue) ? Color.white : Color.blue))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .blue)

        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.red) ? Color.white : Color.red))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .red)

        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.yellow) ? Color.white : Color.yellow))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .yellow)
    }
    .onDeleteCommand {
        if let focusedColor {
            if !isColorDeleted.contains(focusedColor) {
                isColorDeleted.append(focusedColor)
            } else {
                let idx = isColorDeleted.firstIndex(of: focusedColor)!
                isColorDeleted.remove(at: idx)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you press **DELETE** or **Edit > Delete** when a rectangle is focused as I explained, it doesn't anything. In fact, the **Edit > Delete** isn't clickable at all.

Comment: could you clarify how it doesn't work?

Comment: I added some details, mostly at the end @malhal https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74429687/revisions

Comment: @MaxAuMax I'm running into the same issue. My code has a bit more meat on it, with a delete in the sidebar and detail view. When I print to console, I see that the delete only considers the focus on the sidebar item and never gets triggered for the detail view...

Comment: I don't have the fix at this time and it's bugging me, might very well be a framework bug (used to work before I changed to the new nav) and my code can't be simpler `.onDeleteCommand(perform: { print("Delete command received from DETAIL!") })` and this never gets printed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `onDeleteCommand` modifier directly on NavigationSplitView like this:

```
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
    List {
        Text("Main page")
    }
} detail: {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.blue) ? Color.white : Color.blue))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .blue)

        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.red) ? Color.white : Color.red))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .red)

        Rectangle()
            .fill((isColorDeleted.contains(.yellow) ? Color.white : Color.yellow))
            .padding()
            .focusable()
            .focused($focusedColor, equals: .yellow)
    }
}
.onDeleteCommand {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well it's working, I guess the simple things are the best lol. Thanks !
It is not perfect tho, if you want to have multiple views that handles delete, good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

With some input from https://swiftwithmajid.com/2021/03/03/focusedvalue-and-focusedbinding-property-wrappers-in-swiftui, I could solve this problem for me as follows:

- Create the FocusedValues extension.
- Define the @FocusedValue in the view where the NavigationSplitView resides.
- Add the .onDeleteCommand to the NavigationSplitView
- Replace the .onDeleteCommand methods in the content/detail views with the .focusedValue methods

This also works nicely for multiple views. Simply use the .focusedValue method instead of .onDeleteCommand. No further references or parameters required.

```
    import SwiftUI

    extension FocusedValues {

        struct DeleteValueKey: FocusedValueKey {
            typealias Value = () -> Void
        }

        var delete: DeleteValueKey.Value? {
            get { self[DeleteValueKey.self] }
            set { self[DeleteValueKey.self] = newValue }
        }
    }

    struct Ocean: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }

    struct ContentView: View {
        
        private var oceans = [
            Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
            Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
            Ocean(name: "Indian"),
            Ocean(name: "Southern"),
            Ocean(name: "Arctic")
        ]
        
        @FocusedValue (\.delete) var delete
        
        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                NavigationSplitView() {
                    NonWorkingView(oceans: oceans)
                } detail: {
                    WorkingView(oceans: oceans)
                }
                .onDeleteCommand(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }

    struct NonWorkingView: View {
        
        @State var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
        @State var oceans: [Ocean]
        
        func delete() {
            for id in multiSelection { print("\(id) deleted")}
        }
        
        var body: some View {

            List(oceans, selection: $multiSelection) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
            .onDeleteCommand(perform: delete)
            //  ^^^^^^^ DOES NOT work
        }
    }

    struct WorkingView: View {
        
        @State var oceans: [Ocean]
        @State var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
        
        func delete() {
            for id in multiSelection { print("\(id) deleted")}
        }
        
        var body: some View {

            List(oceans, selection: $multiSelection) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
            .focusedValue(\.delete, delete)
            //  ^^^^^^^ DOES work
        }
    }
```